# Скрипт выполняет метод JS, но не выполняет метод jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Добавление дочернего элемента с помощью метода .appendChild() происходит успешно:

```
var divData = document.createElement('div');
$('.element-property__label').parent()[0].appendChild(divData);
```

Добавление с помошью метода .append():

```
 var divData = document.createElement('div');
 $('.element-property__label').parent()[0].append(divData);
```

возвращает ошибку

```
 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).parent(...)[0].append is not a function(…)
```

Comment: это не метод js, это метод оболочки ie или фреймворка. Используйте другие ф-ции. Например parent.appendChild

Comment: таки надо убрать `[0]`, тогда обращение будет идти к объекту jQuery у которого есть метод append

Comment: @nick_n_a я и использую appendChild() https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document#добавление-элемента-appendchild-insertbefore, который работает успешно

Comment: Повторю с другой формулировкой. Что б добавить в текущюю ветку возьмите родителя текущей ветки и добавьте туда детей. Хотя как пишет @Grundy будет правильнее)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, в очередной раз помогаете. но только есть вопрос. почему когда я выполняю  $('.element-property__label').parent() в консоли браузера у меня возвращает коллекцию из одного элемента? из этих соображений я и взял нулевой элемент

Comment: уже пишу ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При обращении к объекту jQuery по индексу, например так

```
$('.element-property__label').parent()[0]
```

Будет получен конкретный [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), а не объект jQuery.

При попытке вызвать у него метод [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append), в некоторых браузерах, например IE будет ошибка говорящая об отсутствии данного метода.

Для того, чтобы вызывать методы объекта jQuery, не нужно получать конкретный элемент из коллекции. Все методы применяются ко всем выбранным элементам.

Поэтому для использования [метода jQuery.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) достаточно просто убрать обращение по индексу.

```
$('.element-property__label').parent().append(divData);
```

---

> в консоли браузера у меня возвращает коллекцию из одного элемента

И это нормально. Интерфейс объекта jQuery унифицирован для работы с внутренней коллекцией. Поэтому не важно сколько именно элементов есть в коллекции и есть ли они вообще.

Comment: "унифицирован для работы с внутренней коллекцией", то есть будет работать с потенциально неограниченной коллекцией? индивидуальная работа с элементом коллекции возможна? или мы должны давать уникальные классы или id, чтобы не раздувать нашу коллекцию?

Comment: @while1pass, честно говоря не понял вопрос. Я имел ввиду, что все методы внутри себя обращаются к _коллекции_, в которой хранятся выбранные элементы. То есть, если в коллекции один элемент - его не надо выбирать отдельно, метод будет работать как с одним элементом, так и с несколькими

Comment: я спрашивал с тем уклоном, что вдруг окажется, что коллекция огромных размеров, а это замедлит обработку данных.

Comment: @while1pass, для того, что бы применить функцию к конкретному элементу, его можно получить в виде jQuery объекта с помощью метода [`eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/), То есть на твоем примере это было бы так: `$('.element-property__label').parent().eq(0).append(divData);`